# Не могу получить данные json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Создал на локальном сервере файл json-data.json

```
[
    "menu": [
      "page-link": {
        "title": "Новости",
        "url": "/index.html"
      },
      "page-link": {
        "title": "Загрузки",
        "url": "/loads.html"
      }
    ]
]
```

есть в html документе список с id = "menu"

```
<ul id = "menu"></ul>
```

Нужно при загрузке файла из json добавлять в спикок элементы списка li, вот так я пытаюсь это сделать

```
window.onload = function() {
    $.get("json-data.json", function (response) {
        for (let i in response.menu) {
            $("#menu").append("<li>" + page-link[i].title + "</li>");
        }
    });
}
```

Но в ответ ничего, консоль пуста. Нарочно делал ошибки в имени фала json, консоль пишет, что ошибка, а вот когда имя правильно, то консоль пуста.

Не могу понять где ошибка и что неправильно, кто подскажет как исправить и таки получить информацию из json файла?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое Вашего файла не является данными, прaвильно записанными в формате JSON. Поэтому в `$.get` происходит ошибка.  Внутри массива должны находиться или native типы, или объекты, завернутые в фигурные скобки.

Ошибка:

```js
var data = [
    "menu": [
      "page-link": {
        "title": "Новости",
        "url": "/index.html"
      },
      "page-link": {
        "title": "Загрузки",
        "url": "/loads.html"
      }
    ]
];
console.log(data);
```

Нет ошибки:

```js
var data = [{
  "menu": [{
    "page-link": {
      "title": "Новости",
      "url": "/index.html"
    },
    "page-link": {
      "title": "Загрузки",
      "url": "/loads.html"
    }
  }]
}];
console.log(data);
```

Comment: и этот код надо добавить в json файл? если так, то ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @YaroslavSaenko Нет, этот код не надо добавить в JSON файл. Не торопитесь и подумайте, что здесь является данными, соответсвующими содержимому файла, а что - кодом, добавленным для наглядности примеров.

Comment: я не понял вашу мысль. Я изменил джейсон файл в соответствии с вашим примером, но без переменной и все осталось по прежнему.